# Why lldb doesn't use ptrace on linux?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, lldb, ptrace

From the output of `strace -o file lldb someprog`, I found there is no `ptrace`.

Then how can lldb get features like `PTRACE_ATTACH/PTRACE_SINGLESTEP` and so on?

Comment: strace -f ... can find ptrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically, the lldb process doesn't do any actual debugging.  Instead, it always uses a proxy (lldb-server on Linux, debugserver on Darwin)(*) to do the actual debugging, and communicates with it using the gdb remote serial protocol.  lldb-server does use ptrace on Linux (and somewhat on Darwin).

(*) I think there still is an in-process adaptor for Windows, but IIRC they are switching to lldb-server as well.